# How Do I Output Delivery Instructions for Magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying to create a script that I can access via URL so that it outputs delivery details, specifically the fields I need to display are: orderID, status, gift_message and a custom customer address attribute that is called "delivery_instructions". So far I have the following, but I am stuck with trying to get the delivery instructions, any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
$myOrder=Mage::getModel('sales/order'); 

$orders=Mage::getModel('sales/mysql4_order_collection');
$message = Mage::getModel('giftmessage/message'); 
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');

$orders->addFieldToFilter('total_paid',Array('gt'=>0)); //Amount paid larger than 0
//$orders->addFieldToFilter('gift_message_id',Array('gt'=>0));

$allIds=$orders->getAllIds();
foreach($allIds as $thisId) {
    $myOrder->reset()->load($thisId);
    $shippingAddress = $myOrder->getShippingAddress();
    $customerDetails = $myOrder->getCustomer();
    //echo $myOrder->shippingaddress->getData('delivery_instructions');
    $customer_id = $myOrder->getCustomerId() . "',";
    echo $customer_id . "',";
        echo "'" . $myOrder->getStatus() . "',";
    echo "'" . $myOrder->getIncrementID() . "',";
    $gift_message_id = $myOrder->getGiftMessageId();
        if(!is_null($gift_message_id)) {
           $message->load($gift_message_id);
           echo $gift_message = $message->getData('message') . "',";
        };
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load( $customer_id); 
echo $customer = $customer->getData('incrementId'); 
echo "\r\n";
echo "<br/ >";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close with this:

```
//echo $myOrder->shippingaddress->getData('delivery_instructions');
```

In order to get the shipping address object you need to use:

```
$myOrder->getShippingAddress()
```

and to get the delivery_instruction from the shipping address object:

```
$myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getDeliveryInstructions()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although this seems to get the field delivery_instructions, instead of the custom attribute which has been created at customer level.

Any thoughts?

Comment: see @i.amniels response ... getting an attribute from any object is something like: $object->getCamelCaseAttributeName()

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom address attributes and custom customer attributes.

Customer attributes can be accessed like this:

```
// A customer is not mandatory for an order.
if($myOrder->getCustomerId()){
    $customer = Mage::getModel(’customer/customer’)->load($myOrder->getCustomerId());
    $customer->getDeliveryInstructions();
}
```

Address attributes can be accessed like this:

```
$myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getDeliveryInstructions();
```